# Provide definition of one method of a template class

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

Is it possible to provide a custom definition of one of the methods of a template class.  Or is it all or nothing, meaning either I have to use all the provided definitions  as is or I have to create / define template specialization of the whole class.

I am writing some test code to better understand writing a custom allocator.  I want to provide a custom definition of allocator::allocate().   Do I have to forward declare allocator.  Or do I have the prototype of allocate() wrong?  Or do I have to provide template specialization for allocator just so I can provide my own definition of allocate().

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <>
std::allocator<int>::pointer 
std::allocator<int>::allocate(size_type n, std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint)
{
    cout << "Doing an alloc for an int allocator" << endl;
    return nullptr;
}

int main()
{
    std::allocator<int> a1; // default allocator for ints
    int* a = a1.allocate(10); // space for 10 ints
}
```

Getting the following error:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 ./t1.cc
./t1.cc:6:78: error: no member function 'allocate' declared in 'std::allocator<int>'
```

I am using g++ 4.7.2.  I looked into the header file "bits/allocator.h" (included from "memory" where class allocator is defined.  Not seeing the method allocate().  Is the method prototype in one of the base class?

Comment: you must put it into the std namespace. And there is no template function specialization in C++. (There is overloading instead, which will not help you in this case)

Comment: @erenon Put "what" in the std namespace?

Answer (score 0):

That's because in gcc, `allocator` is defined thusly:

```
template<typename _Tp>
class allocator: public __glibcxx_base_allocator<_Tp>
{ .. };
```

Where the `allocate()` method itself comes from `__glibcxx_base_allocator`. Now that base is, a few lines later, just removed:

```
// Undefine.
#undef __glibcxx_base_allocator
```

as discouragement to prevent people like you from mucking around in the code!

But, and let me preface this with **DO NOT DO THIS EVER OMG**, in the interest of mucking about, you can find that `__glibcxx_base_allocator` is `#define`d as `__gnu_cxx::new_allocator`, and you can use that knowledge to specialize your function thusly (note that it has to be in the same namespace as the original template - per specialization rules):

```
namespace __gnu_cxx {

    template <>
    new_allocator<int>::pointer
    new_allocator<int>::allocate(
        new_allocator<int>::size_type n,
        std::allocator<void>::const_pointer hint)
    {
        std::cout << "Doing an alloc for an int allocator" << std::endl;
        return nullptr;
    }

}
```

I really cannot stress enough to **NOT DO THIS**. But it was fun to track down.

Comment: Freaking awesome, thank you very much.  Was a very good learning experience.  I have a question. when I use the type std::allocator<int> (in main), the class type gets created by the compiler (include the allocate() version for an int).   And I am providing my own definition.   Why isn't the compiler complaining that there are duplicate definitions of the "same" method.  Or are the two not the same?  If so, how are they different?

Answer (score 0):

Looking through the libstdc++ headers shipped with MinGW g++4.9, the definition of the `allocate` member function is present in the class `new_allocator` which is defined in the header `ext/new_allocator.h`. `std::allocator` publicly inherits from `new_allocator`.

Had libstdc++ chosen to define `allocate` as a member function of `std::allocator` itself, your code would've compiled (it compiles on VS2013 because that implementation of `std::allocator` does define the `allocate` member function), but even so, it would be undefined behavior.

From N3337, *§17.6.4.2.1/2* **[namespace.std]**

> The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares
>       — an explicit specialization of any member function of a standard library class template, or
>   `...`

You'll need to provide your own allocator implementation if you want to customize the behavior.

Comment: Just curious, after thinking about it more, why does the code compile in your environment.  Shouldn't the compiler have complained that there are duplicate definitions of std::allocator<int>::allocate()?

Comment: @AhmedA I don't understand your question. Your example doesn't compile if I use g++, it does if I use MSVC. But there's no question of a duplicate definition because neither implementation provides a specialization of `std::allocator<int>`

Comment: When you say the code compiles in VS2013, because std::allocator defines allocate().  In that case, when I use the type allocator<int> in main, does that not generate a specialization of std::allocator<int>.  And I am also providing one in my cc file.  That's what I meant by duplicate.  Sorry if I am not being clear.

Comment: @AhmedA No, I understand now. That's not how explicit specialization of a member function works. Read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_specialization#Members_of_specializations) (search for *A member or a member template of a class template*). Your explicit specialization will be used in your example (if you get it to compile).